# TestNG update related issue

Tags: eclipse, installation, plugins, testng-eclipse

2 Issue :

1. While check for Update
2. While Updating TestNG

   I have tried to resolve by remove link from 'Install New Software' of dl.bintray and update lnik of Technology but still TestNG version is not updating. please guide me with this.
3. Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
   Software being installed: TestNG P2 Feature 7.9.0.r202312310341 (org.testng.p2.feature.feature.group 7.9.0.r202312310341)
   Missing requirement: slf4j-api 1.7.36 (slf4j.api 1.7.36) requires 'java.package; org.slf4j.impl 1.6.0' but it could not be found
   Cannot satisfy dependency:
   From: TestNG P2 Feature 7.9.0.r202312310341 (org.testng.p2.feature.feature.group 7.9.0.r202312310341)
   To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; slf4j.api [1.7.36,1.7.36]
4. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFQwl.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgSGc.jpg)

by remove link from 'Install New Software' of dl.bintray and update lnik of Technology but still TestNG version is not updating.

Comment: The `org.slf4j.impl` Java package in version 1.6.0 or higher is indeed missing in the `https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site` update site. It is unclear why [this issue](https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse/issues/561) has been closed. So please report it again. As workaround you can use the update `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-06` which contains the `org.slf4j.impl` package in version 1.7.32. What's your second issue? What are you trying to say with your second screenshot (and why is it cropped and where is it from)?